# How to add/join sales_flat_order.customer_firstname column to transaction grid?

Tags: magento-1, sales-order, order-grid, transaction

I have the collection for transaction and I added a line to get `customer_firstname`:

```
  protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = ($this->getCollection())
            ? $this->getCollection() : Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_payment_transaction_collection');
        $order = Mage::registry('current_order');
        if ($order) {
            $collection->addOrderIdFilter($order->getId());
        }
        $collection->addOrderInformation(array('increment_id'));
        $collection->addPaymentInformation(array('method'));
       $collection->joinAttribute('customer_firstname','sales_order/customer_firstname','sales_flat_order.increment_id=sales_payment_transaction.order_id', null,'inner',null);
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

here are the parameters for join attribute function:

```
joinAttribute(
    $alias, 
    $attribute, 
    $bind, 
    $filter = null, 
    $joinType = 'inner', 
    $storeId = null
)
```

so it seems I did not do anything wrong

and then when preparing columns I did this:

```
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
             $this->addColumn('customer_firstname', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('First Name'),
            'index'=>'customer_firstname',
            'type'  => 'text'
        ));
}
```

It doesn't show me anything.how can i achieve this?
I want to have the join

**I don't want to go through the renderer because I know how to do it and I need to do it this way because I need to have filter in this new column**

Comment: Have you tried http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html?

Comment: yes I already did try that and for some reason it breaks the system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm noticing this.

```
sales_flat_order.increment_id = sales_payment_transaction.order_id
```

`increment_id` does not equate to `order_id`. Rather, it should like below.

```
sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_payment_transaction.order_id
```

I typically prefer Zend methods.

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    array('s' => $collection->getTable('sales/order')),
    'main_table.order_id = s.entity_id',
    array('customer_firstname' => 's.customer_firstname')
);
```

You should have `customer_firstname` available as a column on your collection now. Give it a shot!

Comment: Glad I could help!